# Cordova (iOS, WP8) Multiple WebViews

Tags: ios, cordova, windows-phone-8

I need to create a Cordova project for iOS and WP8. It should have a header bar (probably written in jQuery), which will be also a Tab Navigator. As a content of the page there will be external page loaded. Once somebody clicks on a link (from external page) a new tab should be created, added to the header bar as a button and the new page should be displayed as a new WebView. In the same time it is very important to have access to cordova APIs.

Is it possible? I wanted to use the inAppBrowser plugin, but it doesn't support multiple WebViews.

I will be very grateful for any help you can provide!

Best Regards

TD

Answer (score 0):

**From the OP:**

> Once somebody clicks on a link (from external page) a new tab should
>   be created, added to the header bar as a button and the new page
>   should be displayed as a new WebView. In the same time it is very
>   important to have access to cordova APIs.
>
> Is it possible? I wanted to use the inAppBrowser plugin, but it
>   doesn't support multiple WebViews.

**RESPONSE**

The answer is NO. Once you load an external page, especially with the InAppBrowser then you can NO LONGER use the device API.

I've tried to get the documentation fixed, but in this latest round of updates, the documentation got worse.

This paragraph ([from the bug repository](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9470))  should be included in the documentation.

> The InAppBrowser window behaves like a standard web browser, with one major exception - it can not access Cordova APIs. This means many of the core Cordcova plugins are not available, which include - but are limited to accelerometer, battery, compass, and geolocation. For this reason, the InAppBrowser is recommended if you need to load third-party content (that is considered untrusted). In addition, the InAppBrowser is not subject to the whitelist, nor is opening links via the system browser from within InAppBrowser.

Comment: Thank you for your input! 
So if the inAppBrowser plugin cannot be used to do what I was supposed to do, could you please suggest something as an alternative solution? Maybe iFrames or simple Ajax calls would be more suitable to keep an external page within the Cordova and to have an access to Cordova APIs?

Comment: I've changed the inAppBrowser to an iFrame, but the page, which is embedded in the iFrame has some relative paths, and they are blocked. I've noticed that each request has file:/// instead of https:// at the beginning, so I think that this is the problem..

Comment: Sorry, I should have given you this link last time. [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md). At this point you have a common `white-list` issue. You can search on SO or post a new question **_OR_** READ #6, #7, #10 & #11. Note, if you post a new question, let me know (here) and I can post a shortcut method. There is not enough room to answer here. TIA

Comment: Thank You JesseMonroy for your help. Unfortunately, I've read this article, but it hasn't solved my problem. Once I started to use iframe instead of inAppBrowser the external page is partly loaded (i.e. background is loaded), but some of resources are blocked with a message:  "Blocked a frame with origin "https://<hostname>:<port>" from accessing a frame with origin "file://". I have been looking for a solution, but haven't found anything so far.. I have set up the whitelist and CSP to access everything, but there was no change.

Comment: Okay for iOS9 you need to make sure you use 'gap:` in your CSP. For windows, the rules are not clear. I have had trouble finding information; if you find any please let me know. --- At this point I must ask why you are using an external webpage?  I've seem people using them for all sorts of bad reasons; mostly because they do not have a complete understanding of Cordove/Phonegap. TIA

Comment: Sorry, did not get your response. I've been forgetting to tell people. **iOS9 is [not officially support](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/current-tripping-points.md)**

Comment: Thank you Jesse! One more question - Can't inAppBrowser in neither way use Cordova APIs even in _self mode? Maybe there is a kind of workaround?

Comment: Hmmm... interesting you ask that. I've been studying that exact question for the last 24 hours. There is a documentation inconsistency for that exact spot. It says *_self: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.* -- THIS suggests that perhaps what your are asking can be done. However, third paragraph states *The InAppBrowser window behaves like a standard web browser, and* ***can't access Cordova APIs.*** Then the third sentence contradicts what the option for `_self` says. You can try, but I don't think it will work; It should not.

Comment: When I use inAppBrowser no errors occur and the page is loaded fine, but unfortunately, there is no option to create communication between inAppBrowser and Cordova. I've tried each mode of inAppBrowser and still no luck. What I want to do is to create a kind of wrapper for the external webpage using Cordova in order to have Cordova APIs functionalities available. Do you have any other ideas how to do it?

Comment: I've been really clear on this. But I will repeat, If you use inappbrowser, once you load an external page you cannot use the Cordoca APIs. I've said that in every message. It is obscurely written that way in the documentation. The FAQs I have written state this.

Comment: If you want to pass information from the webpage, to Cordova you need an intermediate agent. Most people pass the data to the server, then Cordova asks the server. You cannot pass data from the browser to the Cordova, but Cordova can pass data to the browser.

Comment: It turned out that I have to use iframe, but I am still facing the different protocols problem, which I mentioned above. Is there any chance to make it work? Let's assumed, that this external website is safe, and I have to embed it in the Cordova. .Is there a way to not get these errors related with different protocols?

Comment: You are being very general. It has been over two weeks since i wrote my last message. At this point, I have no idea what your are talking about. I've been very clear. The best that I can make is that you have \*never\* done anything but webbrowser/webserver development, which puts you at a great disadvantage. The easiest thing to do is to tell me what you are trying to accomplish rather that going in circles.

Comment: All I want to achieve is to create a Cordova application, then a local index.html file should contain a header, content and footer. Then, I'd like to embed the whole external page in the content of index.html using iframe. So basically I need to create the app, which will contain the external webpage with the access to the device APIs. My main problem is that many resources of the external page are blocked with a message: "Blocked a frame with origin "https://<hostname>:<port>" from accessing a frame with origin "file://" and the page doesn't work.

Comment: Nope your going in circles again. Talking about some damm iframe BS. You've got to get these ideas of bad architecture out of your head. Whatever you are trying to produce is not coming through. You may in the end use an iframe, but you need a very good reason. The entire mobile App architecture is to get a way from the staid thinking you are presenting. So one more time, what is your end goal? FWIW you CANNOT create *"external webpage with the access to the device APIs"*. This goes again all security protocols. You can have external pages. You can have APIs. But not at the same time.